# How can I tell Apache to log the cause of the redirect?

Tags: apache, redirect

I am migrating a website from one server to a temporary virtual machine on my computer. When I try to access the site on my VM I am redirected to the original server, and I can't find out why.

How can I tell Apache to log the cause of the redirect?

The original server is accessed at http://www.example.com and its content is delivered by WordPress. On this server, I have archived the database, the Apache configuration and the WordPress directory. Then I have imported it on my VM and I have edited wp-config.php to connect to the local database.

Now when I type the IP of my VM in my browser, I receive a 302 and I am redirected to http://www.example.com. The Apache configuration of the site contains no redirects nor rewrite rules, and there is no `.htaccess` in the site's directory.

Here is the configuration of the website on the VM. Every other Apache configuration is the default:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin support@example.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/www/htdocs/wordpress
    ErrorLog "/path/to/www/logs/errors.log"
    CustomLog "/path/to/www/logs/access.log" combined
    RewriteLog "/path/to/www/logs/rewrite.log"

    <Directory "/path/to/www/htdocs/wordpress">

    </Directory>

    <Directory "/path/to/www/htdocs">

          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None

          # Do not answer to this vulnerability scanner.
          BrowserMatchNoCase "Morfeus Scanner" bad_bot
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          Deny from env=bad_bot

          Options +MultiViews
          DirectoryIndex index

          php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen off
          php_admin_flag expose_php off
          php_admin_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
          php_admin_flag safe_mode off
          php_admin_flag display_errors off
          php_admin_flag log_errors on

    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You should check first the DNS resolution, as your VM is named always "www.example.com".